# GridView Docs Code Don't Run, Why?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I was learning about how to use GridView from the official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview#example).
So I tried the Java example code they added and it don't work.
Here the code in case it has been changed in the above link:

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
```

OnCreate() Code:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Custom Java Class (Image Adapter):

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
    };
}
```

It give me "Unfortunately ... Stopped" message right off the bat when I run it.

From the Stack Trace:

```
ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast 
to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
```

If you don't know what the Stack Trace is go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

I followed all the instructions carefully, using the sample images they suggested, and most importantly copied all code from the site itself (including XML).

Anyone can explain.

Comment: You'll have to include your code and a description of what you're trying to do to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: @mypetlion all code I used is found in three blocks which are found the docs link above, also they've stated the wanted result at the very beginning of the example.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks man, your comment really helped me figuring out why. I think they've got a mistake in their code, I'll write an answer to myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they've got a mistake in their code. So I partially changed a line in the third block in the `if` block of `getView()` to be as the following one:

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```